# Getting data from API before rendering component React, Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My initialstate in redux store is

```
const initialState = {
  token:localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isAuthenticated: null,
  isLoading: false,
  user:null,


}
```

My app component looks like:**store.dispatch(loadUser());** check the token of local storage and load user from API if token is exists and correct.

```
class App extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
  store.dispatch(loadUser());
}
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Provider store={store}>        
      <Router>            
          <BaseRouter/>            
      </Router>
    </Provider>  
  </div>
 );
 }
}

export default App;
```

everything works fine, but when I reload  component in browser it immediately redirect me to  component, despite the redux dev tools shows that user is loaded and **isAuthenticated:true**.My question is : How I can load my redux store before render() function?? Or is there any other ideas to make it work correctly??

```
class ArticleList extends Component{
static propTypes = {
    articles: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getArticles: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.props.getArticles();
}
render(){
    console.log('is_auth',this.props.isAuthenticated);// console shows NULL
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />;
      }
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <Articles data={this.props.articles}/>     
        </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
  const mapStateToProps = state =>({
articles: state.articleReducer.articles,
isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated
})

 export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getArticles})(ArticleList);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume that the `isAuthenticated` property in your Redux store is not synced with the `localStorage` ? So if you reload the page, it will take the value in the default state, which is `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArticleList` is being rendered even before `isAuthenticated` is updated as true. Hence the redirection is happening everytime. This can be solved by waiting the main router's render until authentication is complete. 
Eg :

```
function BaseRouter(props) {
  return !props.isLoading ? (
    <Router>
      <Route />
      <Route />
      <Route />
    </Router>
  ) : null;
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ isLoading: state.authReducer.isLoading });
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BaseRouter);
```

This will block all routes till authentication check is complete. If you need to enable some routes which do not require authentication, apply conditional render.